# is it possible to capture UDID with php

Tags: ios, udid

I dont want to use $_SERVER['HTTP_X_UNIQUE_ID']; because some browser issues.

Is there a way to do that with php for iPhone/iPad?

And leave it with an echo?

Comment: This site, http://get.udid.io, allows access to UDIDs, but only after the user installs a certificate, so I'm guessing that you can't access it without doing that.

Comment: it should be possible i can write it to my database with this $_SERVER['HTTP_X_UNIQUE_ID']; only i want to display it in browser using php

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a way prior to iOS 7 to access the UDID; with iOS 7 that API no longer returns the UDID.  I looked into this when all of a sudden my instructions to users for getting me their UDID to let me register them for beta testing weren't working any more.  The API is still there - it just returns useless (AFAIK) information.

The only way to obtain the UDID with ios7 or later is to have the physical phone plugged into iTunes & cut & paste.

no PHP.  no Objective C.  Nuthin'.

Comment: oke thru $_SERVER['HTTP_X_UNIQUE_ID']; i can catch in database http://postimg.org/image/58xsobk6l/ and this is captured on iOS 7